# Exception "Back-end (JVM) Internal error: wrong bytecode generated" is thrown when building android application with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have an android project with an util class in kotlin for doing all network requests,
The thing, i have done another helper class to manage the response of the request when doing it with a session.

Interface `Session`:

```
interface Session : Serializable {
    suspend fun <T> withSession(callback: suspend (headers: Map<String, String>) -> ApiResponse<T>): T
    suspend fun refreshSession(params: HashMap<String, String>)
}
```

Implementation of interface `Session`:

```
class ApiSession(
    token: String,
    private val refreshToken: String) : Session {

    private val headers: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap()

    init {
        headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer $token"
    }

    override suspend fun <T> withSession(callback: suspend (headers: Map<String, String>) -> ApiResponse<T>): T {
        val response = callback(headers)

        if (response.ok)
            return response.data

        //TODO: Retry connection or exception
        return response.data
    }

    override suspend fun refreshSession(params: HashMap<String, String>) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

`SuccessCallback` definition:

```
typealias SuccessCallback<T> = (response: T?) -> T
```

The problem is with the next method of the helper class `NetworkFunnel`,

Where `requestQueue` is a `Volley.newRequestQueue(context)` object

when i have this:

```
private suspend fun <T : Jsonable<T>> requestWithSession(session: Session, url: String, method: Int, body: JSONObject?, clazz: Class<T>, onSuccess: SuccessCallback<T>): T {
    val response = session.withSession { headers ->

        return@withSession suspendCoroutine<ApiResponse<T>> { cont ->
            val req = object : JsonObjectRequest(method, url,
                body ?: JSONObject(),
                {response ->
                    val instance = clazz.newInstance()
                    val apiResponse = ApiResponse(true, instance.fromJsonObject(response))
                    cont.resume(apiResponse)
                },
                {error ->

                }
            ) {
                override fun getHeaders() = headers
            }

            requestQueue.add(req)
        }
    }

    return onSuccess(response)
}
```

When complie, the next error is thrown:

```
e: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: wrong bytecode generated
```

But when i distribute the method above like this:

```
private suspend fun <T : Jsonable<T>> requestWithSession(session: Session, url: String, method: Int, body: JSONObject?, clazz: Class<T>, onSuccess: SuccessCallback<T>): T {
    val response = session.withSession { headers ->

        return@withSession suspendCoroutine<ApiResponse<T>> { cont ->
            val req = parseResponse(cont, headers, url, method, body, clazz)

            requestQueue.add(req)
        }
    }

    return onSuccess(response)
}

private fun <T : Jsonable<T>> parseResponse(cont: Continuation<ApiResponse<T>>, headers: Map<String ,String>, url: String, method: Int, body: JSONObject?, clazz: Class<T>): JsonObjectRequest {
    return object : JsonObjectRequest(method, url,
        body ?: JSONObject(),
        {response ->
            val instance = clazz.newInstance()
            val apiResponse = ApiResponse(true, instance.fromJsonObject(response))
            cont.resume(apiResponse)
        },
        {error ->

        }
    ) {
        override fun getHeaders() = headers
    }
}
```

All is going well and requests are made as expected, anyone knows what is happening here? i'm very lost...

I'm using kotlin version `1.3.72`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace --debug` to find out the cause of the specific error.

In addition, you can try to upgrade the version of kotlin to compile the program again

Comment: My kotlin version is 1.3.72, and the error has'nt got any details is just sayng that "Back-end (JVM) Internal error: wrong bytecode generated"

Comment: You can try my answer